# How can I enable OpenGL drawing in Photoshop when I have two display adaptors, only one of which is capable?

Tags: multiple-monitors, adobe-photoshop, opengl

I have a dual-monitor setup running Windows 7 and Photoshop CS5. One monitor is plugged into the motherboard's on-board output (which shows up in device manager as `Intel(R) HD Graphics Family`). My other monitor is plugged into a Radeon HD 6450, which is certainly capable of handling OpenGL drawing in Photoshop.

Despite this, the options are all grayed out, and the message `No GPU options available with Photoshop Standard` is displayed.

Is there a way of making this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to set the display connected to your fast graphics card as the primary monitor. You can still drag the taskbar back to the other monitor once this is done.

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop does not support dual video card setup, plug both monitors into your Radeon HD 6450 and disable your (inferior) board video, problem solved. Use VGA>DVI adapter for 2nd monitor if needed.